I want to know for a relay having different contacts some contacts are shown by dotted line and some by solid line. How dotted line contacts works?
I want to know for a relay having different contacts (shown in drawing) some contacts are shown by dotted line and some by solid line. How dotted line contacts works?


Dotted line is not an electrical connection, it is showing which "electromagnet" in the relay is affecting which switch.

Also, having a single standard relay (or SSR) in an emergency stop circuit is highly questionable practice. Industry practice is to use safety relays where the state of n contacts are mechanically latched together, then add supervision on one of the contacts. 010-K5 might be an attempt of that, but if the rest of the relays are plain ones, that still leaves us with a dangerous nonsense circuit. A relay being a component which we know for sure will eventually fail.

The dotted lines show the relationship between a particular magnetic coil and the associated electrical contacts/switch. This allows a relay in such a schematic to be broken into logical parts, the coil and the contacts that are spatially separated in the schematic, but logically associated.

I'd say "logically associated" is actually "physically associated"

@EugeneSh. Yes, they are also physically associated. But certainly they are logically associated. Energizing the coil at one end of the dotted line actives the contacts at the other end of the dotted line.

@EugeneSh. Relay all contacts are operated mechanically once its coil gets energised.  So it means that all contacts would be shown by dotted line

Be aware, that your schematic is simplified and doesn't show complete path for current(s).
To show what this represent, it is vital to understand that relay (or contactor) has two sections: coil (or solenoid) marked as rectangular with diagonal line and set of contacts. Dotted line marks mechanical dependency.
When the solenoid is energised, attracts the mechanical part of contacts and set of contacts marked NC (normally closed) goes to open state, the other, NO (normally open) closes.
See this picture: Non-energised state. Bulb off, no current.

And then, lets energise the coil:

